# How can I preserve the state of an HTML element after its animation?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am building a piano visualizer in React so that when the user presses a pianokey, a rectangle div expands out of the top (its height increases) continuously until the user un-presses the key, at which time the rectangle div will move upwards (bottom var increases), getting deleted when the bottom of the div is past the top of the screen.

Currently I am doing this with css animation which plays expand_up infinitely when the user presses a key, and then when they un-press the key, switches the animation to move_up. The issue is that there is no default height specified outside of the animation (which is what I want as I want the height to be determined by expand_up), and so after the div changes animation, its height reverts to 0.

I have tried getting the height before animation change, and then setting the div to that height which gets the height successfully but the elements height does not change. I have also tried to specify the style variable on the JSX div creation through a height array:

```
let [height_dic, set_height_dic] = useState({})
<div style={{height: counter in height_dic ? `${height_dic[counter]}px` : 'auto'}> </div>
```

but the height remains 'auto' even when the a matching counter variable key is added to the height_dic. I have a feeling it has something to do with the element not rerendering. Below is the code in the current state.

**Inside PianoVisual Component**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (this_pressed) {
      // I NEED TO CREATE VISUAL INSTANCE HERE
      set_key_down(true)
      play_sound()

      set_visuals(prev_state => ({
          ...prev_state,
          [counter]: (
          <div ref={ref => visual_refs.current[counter] = ref} className='visualizer-instance expand_up'></div>
          )
      })) 

    } else {
      if (key_down) {
        // I NEED CHANGE ANIMATION FROM EXPAND TO MOVE HERE
        let curr_visual = visual_refs.current[counter]
        curr_visual.classList.remove('expand_up')
        curr_visual.classList.add('move_up')
        const { top, height } = visual_refs.current[counter].getBoundingClientRect()
        curr_visual.style.height = `${height}px`


        curr_visual.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
          // set_visuals(visuals.filter((visual) => visual.id !== id));
          delete visual_refs.current[counter];
        })
          
        set_counter(prev_state => prev_state + 1)
        set_key_down(false)
      
      }
    }
  }, [this_pressed])

return (
    <div className={`piano-key-wrapper ${color}-wrapper`}>
      <div className={`vis-path`} >
          {Object.keys(visuals).map((key, index) => {
            return visuals[key]
          })}
      </div>
      <div ref={innerRef} className={`piano-key ${color}-key ${key_down ? 'pressed' : ''}`} 
      onMouseUp={() => set_this_pressed(false)} onMouseDown={() => set_this_pressed(true)} onMouseLeave={() => set_this_pressed(false)} >{keyboard_key}</div>
    </div>
    
  )
```

**CSS animations**

```
@keyframes expand_up {
    0% {
        position: absolute;
        height: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    100% {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 300000px;
    }
}

@keyframes move_up {
    0% {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    100% {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 300000px;
    }
}

.visualizer-instance {
    background-color: var(--ten-color);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.expand_up {
    animation: expand_up 1000s linear;
}

.move_up {
    animation: move_up 1000s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I preserve the state of an HTML element after its animation?

use [fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

```css
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Comment: Hm, this doesnt seem to work for me. Could it be because I am ending the animation before its supposed to? I put it on .expand_up and .move_up.

Comment: where are you defining the fill mode ?
you should define it either after the animation shortcut: ```css
animation: move_up 1000s linear;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```
or within the animation shortcut: `animation: move_up 1000s linear forward;`

Comment: Also, instead of removing, and adding classes, you can use [pause](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/pause), and [play](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/play) methods of the animation.

Comment: Defining the animations in javascript and using pause and play worked for me. Thanks!